Unable to execute request for an existing session: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException for selenium tests triggered from Jenkins on GKE cluster
Chrome: node-chrome:123.0.6312.86-chromedriver-123.0.6312.86-grid-4.19.1-20240402
selenium/hub:4.19.1-20240402
dotnet 6
We have our selenium grid/tests run on parallel nodes on GKE cluster. Since sunday we are seeing the following exception
Unable to execute request for an existing session: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

and the tests are failing intermittently. We are also getting exceptions while capturing screenshots for most of the tests. While we are seeing the following screenshots for some tests, where some random html elements load instead of the actual application. This is blocking our regression cycle and we are out of ideas. Any pointers/help is much appreciated


OS Update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-9-2024-kb5036896-os-build-17763-5696-efb580f1-2ce4-4695-b76c-d2068a00fb92
Patch Update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-9-2024-kb5036610-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8-for-windows-10-version-1809-and-windows-server-2019-7bc45b68-b12c-401a-9394-1cc578bf122e
The issue has been resolved after removing/reverting the above patch updates in our environment

OS Update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-9-2024-kb5036896-os-build-17763-5696-efb580f1-2ce4-4695-b76c-d2068a00fb92
Patch Update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/april-9-2024-kb5036610-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8-for-windows-10-version-1809-and-windows-server-2019-7bc45b68-b12c-401a-9394-1cc578bf122e
The issue has been resolved after removing/reverting the above patch updates in our environment
